# "Dockerized" Node.js Application not connecting via my browser

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, mern

I have a MERN stack application that I created a docker image for and it is running via docker container. The application also uses a redis database which has its own docker container.
I started it with this code:

```
docker run -t --net host -p 5000:5000 <conatainer-image>
```

It is running on docker when I checked the docker logs.
However, it is not reachable via my browser when I checked `localhost:5000`. The error message is `This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.`

Here is my node server.js

```
   //connect to mongodb server
  const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


  const server = http.createServer(app);


 const start = async () => {
  try {
await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL)
server.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
  );
 } catch (error) {
console.log(error);
 }
};

start();

 My dockerfile:

FROM  node:lts-alpine

 WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

COPY client/package*.json client/
RUN npm run install-client --only=production


 COPY api/package*.json api/
RUN npm run install-api --only=production



COPY client/ client/
RUN npm run client-build --prefix client


 COPY api/ api/



USER node

CMD [ "npm", "start", "--prefix", "api" ]



 EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to disable Docker networking using `--net host` (and it will actively cause problems on non-Linux host systems); does removing that option make a difference?  (You do probably need to attach the container to the same `docker network create` network the Redis container is using, and you may need to adjust the Redis host name in your configuration.)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Actually, I am new to docker, using this stuff to learn. The reason I used the --net host is because that was an answer given to me by one user here. Initially, my nodejs application running in docker container was not seeing the redis container. That led to the redis connection failure. So, I was asked to add --net host to the docker command and it worked. That was when I discovered yet another problem that I couldn't access it via my localhost on the browser. So, I am looking for how best to connect both containers and access my node application on browser.